# ow do I get RectTransform to display on the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I am newbie to Unity and C# but not to programming, so I have been trying to create a card game but I having some challenges. I am trying to generate cards randomly to the hand panel of the player, but the cards are not being displayed on the game screen though when i click the play button the cards are generated in the hierarchy tab but never displayed. I also created a UI>Panel object graphically where i wanted to display the cards but seem to have failed. Here is my code snippet

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cardPrefab; // The prefab for card objects in your UI
    public RectTransform handPanel; // The panel where you want to display the player's hand
    public Text cardsLeftText; // The UI text element to display the number of cards left
    public int maxHandSize = 5; // Maximum number of cards in the player's hand

    private List<CardClass> playerHand = new();
    private CardDataBase cardDatabase;

    private void Start()
    {
        cardDatabase = GetComponent<CardDataBase>();
        DrawInitialHand();
    }

    private void DrawInitialHand()
    {
        DrawRandomCards(maxHandSize);
    }

    private void DrawRandomCards(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (CardDataBase.cardList.Count > 0)
            {
                int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, CardDataBase.cardList.Count);
                CardClass randomCard = CardDataBase.cardList[randomIndex];
                playerHand.Add(randomCard);
                CardDataBase.cardList.RemoveAt(randomIndex);

                // Create a card object in the UI
                GameObject cardObject = Instantiate(cardPrefab, handPanel);
                // Set the card's sprite and other properties
                cardObject.GetComponent<DisplayCard>().SetCardData(randomCard);

                UpdateCardsLeftText();
            }
            else
            {
                // The cardList is empty, handle this case as needed
                Debug.LogWarning("No more cards in the cardList!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCardsLeftText()
    {
        int cardsLeft = CardDataBase.cardList.Count;
        cardsLeftText.text = "Cards Left: " + cardsLeft.ToString();
    }

    public void DrawCardsForPlayer()
    {
        int cardsNeeded = maxHandSize - playerHand.Count;

        if (cardsNeeded > 0)
        {
            DrawRandomCards(cardsNeeded);
        }
    }
}
```

This is supposed to display random cards on the UI>panel (HandPanel) that i graphically created in Unity. It generates the cards though it does not display them.
The other code snippet that I think is important is here.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DisplayCard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<CardClass> displayCard = new();
    public int displayId;
    public int id;
    public int power;
    public string CardName;
    public Sprite spriteImage;

    public Text nameText;
    public Image artImage;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       displayCard.Add(CardDataBase.cardList[displayId]);
       displayCard[0]= CardDataBase.cardList[displayId];

        id = displayCard[0].id;
       CardName = displayCard[0].cardName; 
       spriteImage = displayCard[0].spriteImage;

       nameText.text ="" + CardName; 
       artImage.sprite = spriteImage;


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
      
    }

     public void SetCardData(CardClass card)
    {
        id = card.id;
        CardName = card.cardName;
        spriteImage = card.spriteImage;

        nameText.text = CardName;
        artImage.sprite = spriteImage;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is me using the **RectTransform** type declaration but I have failed to connect it the UI HandPanel i created. Any help to push me i the right direction would be so helpful. Keep in mind the other code functionalities work properly just that it is not displaying anything. As you can see in the screenshot, the Green area is the panel I created manually through the UI  part. And the hierarchy tab shows that the cards have generated.

[image]

Comment: you say it doesnt display it, so, if you make one by hand and compare it to one made by your code what are the differences

Comment: @BugFinder Yes it does not display, but when its in game mode it shows that it has generated the 5 cards(Clone) but I cannot see them in the game mode. Let me share screenshots too

Comment: right - so you ignored the whole question... I will repeat.. if you make one by hand.. ** what are the differences **

Comment: I am having a challenge understanding your question, this is what i pick from your question "what is the difference of one i create manually and that i create with the code?" The difference is that the one the code generates randomly from the database and keeps adding a card whenever they go below 5 cards unlike my manually made  cards, they can't be random. I hope this is the answer to your question

Comment: Most of the reason people cant solve an issue is because they cant accurately articulate the problem. This seems to apply here. You cant seem to tell me what the difference between a manually made one and a code made one. If the the prefab is right. Then the code arguably looks like it should work. So you need to spot the difference and fix it.  From the picture.  You could try setting the parent.